# DataGridView with thread vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, datagridview

**I hav problem when i use DataGridView1 with thread 
i get empty rows like image **

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf grid)

    thread.Start()
End Sub
Public Function grid()

    For i As Int16 = 1 To 50
        Invoke(Sub()
                   DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i)
                   DataGridView1.Refresh()
               End Sub)

    Next
End Function
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOXRR.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GAjg.jpg)

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense. Do you understand what `Invoke` does? You are creating a new thread and then, 50 times, you invoke code on the UI thread to add a row to the grid.  What's the point of the new thread in the first place if basically all the work is done on the UI thread anyway and you also have the overhead of switching back and forth between threads?

Comment: If this is a simplified example then it is still almost certainly wrong. If you have time consuming work to do, do it ALL in one go and package all the data into a single list, then bind that list to the grid in one go at the end.

Comment: Even when you ditch the threading, and put Rows.Add(i) in the button lick event, will create empty rows. So it has nothing to do with thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect example of why you MUST read the relevant documentation, especially if something doesn't work the way you expect.  If you had bothered to read the documentation for the `Add` method you're calling [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewRowCollection_Add_System_Int32_) then you'd have seen that that particular overload adds the specific number of rows to the grid and that's all.  At no point does it populate those rows with any data.  The code you have is going to add 1+2+3+4+...+48+49+50 empty rows to your grid.  If what you actually want is to add a single row each time where `i` is the data displayed in that row then you need to call one of the overloads of `Add` that does that, or else call the overload with no arguments to add a single row, then get that row and set the `Value` of a cell explicitly.

EDIT: The simplest way to add a row with `i` as data is to call the overload of `Add` that takes an array of cell values.  If you only have one cell, you use an array with one element:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add({i})
```

The braces indicate that the contents is an array.  It's shorthand for this:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Integer() {i})
```

Note that, if you pass a single `Integer`, the overload with a single `Integer` parameter will be called as it's the closest match.  If you were to pass multiple discrete `Integers`, e.g.

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, i)
```

then you would not have the same problem because there is no overload with multiple `Integer` parameters.  In that case, the overload that takes an array of `Objects` would be called.  That overload's parameter is declared `ParamArray`, which means that you can pass either multiple individual objects or a single array.  Another option would be to cast your `Integer` as type `Object`, which would also cause the overload that takes an array of `Objects` to be called:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(CObj(i))
```

When you call an overloaded method, the closest valid match will be called, so be sure that your arguments match the parameters of the overload you want to call and make sure you understand what each overload does.  ALWAYS read the documentation if you aren't 100% sure.  The F1 key and the Help menu are there for a reason.